Gradient systems
This is how the gradient system has been defined in the book I have been reading (see the image):


In the gradient system (4), with V(x, y, z) below, I am trying to figure out and clearly understand what the sketch looks like for some of the surfaces  V(x, y, z) = constant and some of the trajectories of the system.
Equation:
$$ V(x, y, z) = x^2 + y^2 - z $$
I think the surfaces are paraboloids with their vertices on the z-axis, and the trajectories show that x  and y  decay exponentially toward 0 as t approaches infinity. However, my understanding of this is not very clear.

setting to zero would likely help. your intuition is right. $z=x^2+y^2+c$ is a vertical shift by $c$

thanks, if i understand - i tried to visualize it but still not certain if the trajectories are making sense here. it seems like I can't attach what I got here in the comments

@DavidP I sketched a paraboloid but it turns out I am still uncertain how to show the trajectories in the sketch.
